# Can bintprog be used with a mod 2 equation constraint on MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, binary, linear-programming

Is there a way to solve a binary minimization problem on MATLAB, where instead of the equation constraint there is a modular constraint, that is, instead of A*x=b there is for example A*x=b (mod 2)? I've tried using bintprog, but can't figure out how to add this condition. Is there a solver for binary nonlinear programming?

Comment: I am guessing the objective function is real valued? (i.e. not subject to a parity constraint)

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't, because mod 2 is not a linear operator. bintprog is used only for liniear equations.